# Data/print error with infinite loop of irrelevant data

Tags: c++, templates, memory, destructor

**EDITED**

I have some problems, probably with the destructor, but I can't find the problem. I'm pretty new to cpp so I'm not exactly sure why and when the destructor is called, but when I try to debug my code I find no issues and get everything printed correctly, but when I run it without debugging it prints just the Hello World and that's it.
How can I fix this if in debug I don't see it?
Where is the problem?

My code looks like that : (EDITED)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

#include "dummy.h"
using namespace std;

#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
    struct Node {
        Node(const T &in) : data(in) {}
        T data;
        Node * next;
    };

    class Iterator
    {
        Node *m_ptr;              // pointer to current node in the list
    public:
        Iterator(Node * node) {
            m_ptr = node;
        }
        Iterator& operator ++ () {
            m_ptr = m_ptr -> next();
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator ++ (T) {
            Iterator temp(*this);
            m_ptr = m_ptr -> next();
            return temp;
        }
        bool operator == (const Iterator other) const {
            return m_ptr == other.m_ptr;
        }
        bool operator != (const Iterator other) const {
            return m_ptr != other.m_ptr;
        }
        T& operator * () {
            return m_ptr -> data();
        }
        operator bool() {
            return m_ptr != 0;
        }
    };

    Node * head;

public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }
    LinkedList(T value) {
        head = new Node(value);
        head -> data = value;
        head -> next = nullptr;
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        while(head != nullptr) {
            Node * n = head -> next;
            free(head);
            head = n;
        }
    }

    void operator = (T &t) {
        head = t.head;
    }

    Node * nodeCopy(Node * head) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        Node * copied_node = new Node(head -> data);
        copied_node -> data = head -> data;
        copied_node -> next = nodeCopy(head -> next);
        return copied_node;
    }

    LinkedList(LinkedList &list){
        head = nodeCopy(list.head);
    }


    template<typename B>
    LinkedList filter(LinkedList &list, B pred) {
        LinkedList <T> new_list(list);
        Node * curr = list.head;
        while (curr) {
            if (!(pred(curr -> data))) {
                new_list.remove(curr -> data);
            }
            curr = curr -> next;
        }

        return new_list;
    }

    int length() {
        int counter = 0;
        Node * tmp = head;
        while( tmp ) {
            counter++;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    void insert(T value) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new Node(value);
//            head -> data = value;
//            head -> next = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        Node* n = new Node(value);

        Node* tmp = head;
        while (tmp != nullptr) {
           if (value > tmp -> data && tmp -> next != nullptr) {
               if (tmp -> next -> data > value) {
                   Node * curr = tmp -> next;
                   tmp -> next = n;
                   n -> next = curr;
                   return;
               } else {
                   tmp = tmp -> next;
               }
           } else if (value > tmp -> data && tmp -> next == nullptr) {
               tmp -> next = new Node(n -> data);
               n -> next = nullptr;
               tmp -> next = n;
               return;
           } else if (value == tmp -> data && tmp -> next == NULL) {
               tmp -> next = new Node(n -> data);
               n -> next = nullptr;
               tmp -> next = n;
               return;
           } else if (value == tmp -> data && tmp -> next != NULL) {
               n -> next = tmp -> next;
               tmp -> next = n;
               return;
           } else {
               n -> next = tmp;
               head = n;
               return;
           }
        }
    }

    void remove(T value) {
        Node * tmp = head;
        while (tmp) {
            if (tmp -> data < value && tmp -> next == nullptr) {
                return;
            } else if (tmp -> data < value && tmp -> next -> data == value) {
                Node * ptr = tmp -> next -> next;
                free(tmp -> next);
                tmp -> next = ptr;
                return;
            } else {
                tmp = tmp -> next;
            }
        }
    }

    void print() {
        Node * curr = head;
        while (curr) {
            cout << curr -> data << endl;
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
    }

    Iterator begin() {
        return head;
    }
    Iterator end() {
        Node * curr = head;
        while (curr) {
            if (curr -> next == nullptr) {
                return curr;
            }
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
    }
};


#endif
```

My main is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sortedList.h"
#include "dummy.h"

bool func(Dummy num) {
    int number = num.get();
    if (number % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    Dummy teeth(24);
    teeth.add(7);
    Dummy slime(11);
    slime.add(1);
    Dummy josh(32);
    LinkedList<Dummy> teeth_list;
    teeth_list.insert(teeth);
    teeth_list.insert(slime);
    teeth_list.insert(josh);
    int num = teeth_list.length();
    cout << "The length is: " << num << endl;
    teeth_list.remove(josh);
    teeth_list.print();
    cout << "Now printing teeth_list list" << endl;
    teeth_list.insert(josh);

    teeth_list.print();

    LinkedList<Dummy> dummy;
    dummy = teeth_list.filter(teeth_list, func);
    cout << "Now printing dummy list after filtering" << endl;
    dummy.print();

    return 0;
}
```

And the console log looks like this after I try to run it:

```
 C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\cmake-build-debug\exe_name.exe
Hello, World!

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by 
Ctrl+C)
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of code to go through! But one thing that jumped out at me as a code smell is your `LinkedList(T value)` constructor: you assign values to the `head` members but don't actually create a `Node` object that `head` points to.

Comment: If behavior changes under a debugger, that is a great indicator that your program has Undefined Behavior.  Make sure to turn on all of your compiler warnings if you haven't already.  Also, depending on which compiler you are using, you may be able to turn on extra analyzers to look specifically for UB (e.g. `-fsanitize=undefined` in GCC and Clang)

Comment: At least your usage of `malloc()` is wrong. `head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(head));` (for example) allocates for `head` (one pointer), but you should allocate for what `head` points (`*head`). Also you shouldn't use `malloc()` in C++. You should use `new` instead.

Comment: What is there reason you use `malloc()` in C++? Especially you use it wrong - `Node* n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(n));` and using proper operator `new` would fix this issue.

Comment: @AdrianMole added this line to the constructer- head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(head)); but it does the same thing :( (nice name by the way ^.^)

Comment: @Slava  how do you use *new* in this situation? just like... head = new head; ?

Comment: You use it with type `head = new Node;` and if you create proper ctor you can use `head = new Node(value);` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard library, the end iterator is one place past the end of the container. To be compatible with the standard library, your `end()` method should be:

```
Iterator end()
{
    return Iterator(nullptr);
}
```

It is probably a good idea to write some unit tests too, maybe with [Googletest](https://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html). With your original code, this test should fail:

```
ASSERT_EQ(instance.length(), std::distance(instance.begin(), instance.end()) 
    << "Distance between begin and end iterators should be the same as length";
```